# Vaadin Widgetset compilation workflow

Tags: java, continuous-integration, workflow, vaadin

What is the optimal workflow for vaadin widgetset compilation?

The widgetset doesnt change all that often, so it seems wasteful to compile it every single time on a checkin, in the CI.
On the other hand, I am not sure if checking in, what  essentially should be compiled, in source control is wise.

What does your vaadin widgetset compilation workflow look like?

Answer (score 2):

In my workspace, I build the widgetset "On Demand" - i.e. I know (or my IDE - IntelliJ - knows) when the widgetset needs te be rebuilt, and so I kick of the build manually.

On our CI server, we build everything, every time - including the widgetset.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a maven multimodule project where one of the submodules is widgetset. If you version it separately from the server-side app, your CI won't have to recompile it for server side changes. For an example, see my iPad CRM demo app at GitHub/jojule